# SQL database replication best practice

Tags: sql-server, transactional-replication

I have a project that require the following:

The main SQL server and database will be in headquarters and two remote locations need to work with their system offline, due to frequent internet failure, but the data has to be replicated to the corporate SQL database.

The remote locations need to have the same data but only in a few tables (for example employees, and other catalogs) and the corporate database must have to have all the remote locations data.

This guarantee that the corporate database will have the latest remote locations data in case the CEO wants to check something.

So I was thinking in transactional replication between remote location and corporate DB but dont know if the approach is ok and also if I need to change my tables because all primary keys are INT incremental and maybe that will create problems in corporate DB because I will have the same key in remote location A and same key in remote location B but for different employees.

Any clue or advise? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If your subscribers are going to be read-only, this will work just fine, even with the identity column as your primary key. I've done it a lot in that sort of scenario and have had no problems. Just be a little careful with the term "guarantee"; there's no such thing in this business, only hedged bets.